# Accessing Auth0 logged in user from within an API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, jwt, auth0

I have a React app which is using auth0 along side an express API server.

My question is, I can get the user information in the client side from the Auth0 user object, but i'm not sure how to access it within the api when a secure end point is called.

Sending the information to the api with any requests seems much less secure than using the access token somehow in the backend but i'm unsure how to do it or if it's even possible.

API SERVER

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 8000
const jwt = require('express-jwt')
const cors = require('cors')

var jwtCheck = jwt({
    secret: '',
    audience: 'http://localhost:8000',
    issuer: 'https://dev-ml4yg9zg.us.auth0.com/',
    algorithms: ['HS256']
});

app.use(cors())

app.get('/unprotected',(req,res) =>{
    res.send("not secured resource")
})

app.get('/authed', jwtCheck,(req,res) =>{
    
    // GET THE DATA FOR THE LOGGED IN USER WHO MADE THE CALL
    
    res.send("secured resource")
})

app.listen(port, () =>{
    console.log(`app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

REACT APP

```
import React,{useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'
import {useAuth0} from '@auth0/auth0-react'

function App() {

  const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState(null)
  const [userMetaData, setUserMetadata] = useState(null)

  const {
      loginWithRedirect, 
      logout, 
      user, 
      isAuthenticated,
      isLoading,
      getAccessTokenSilently
  } = useAuth0()

  console.log(user)

  const getToken = async () => {
    try {
      const accessToken = await getAccessTokenSilently({
        audience: `http://localhost:8000`,
        scope: "read:current_user",
      });

      setAccessToken(accessToken)
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.message);
    }
  };


  const callProtected = () =>{
    axios.get('http://localhost:8000/authed',{
        headers:{
          Authorization:`Bearer ${accessToken}`
        }
      }).then(res =>{
        console.log(res.data)
      }).catch(e =>{
        console.log(e)
      })
  }

  const callUnprotected = ()=>{
    axios.get('http://localhost:8000/unprotected')
    .then(res =>{
      console.log(res.data)
    }).catch(e =>{
      console.log(e)
    })
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => loginWithRedirect()}>Login</button>
      <button onClick={() => logout({returnTo:window.location.origin})}>Log out</button>
      <button onClick={() => getToken()}>Get token</button>
      <button onClick={() => callUnprotected()}>Call unprotected resource</button>
      <button onClick={() => callProtected()}>Call protected resource</button>
      <div>
        User : {user?.name}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I wasn't aware of the User Management API

To solve the issue of getting the user data to confirm authentication within my API server I decoded the JWT token server-side which contained the user ID, then I used the ID within a call to the management API to get the full user data.

The auth token for the call to the management API can be generated within the API dashboard on the Auth0 website

```
app.get('/authed', jwtCheck, async (req,res) =>{
    
    let token = req.headers.authorization.substring(7, req.headers.authorization.length)
    // GET THE DATA FOR THE LOGGED IN USER WHO MADE THE CALL
    var decoded = jwt_decode(token);
    console.log(decoded.sub)

    axios.get(`https://************.us.auth0.com/api/v2/users/${decoded.sub}`,{
        headers:{
            Authorization:`Bearer *`,
        }
    }).then((res) =>{
        console.log(res)
    }).catch(e =>{
        console.log(e)
    })

    res.send("secured resource")
})
```